# Delete a file in "Shared With Me" in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I have a file that was shared with me by a public link. Now when I try to delete this file in "Shared With Me", the file immediately returns into the "Shared With Me" folder again. Is there a way to delete this file?

Comment: It will show the message "Removing one file...". Then it will show "Removed file. One removed file will still be accessible to the collaborators". But the file will still be there. Even after I refresh the page.

Comment: @pnuts I had added the file once. I deleted it after it had no use. I am not the owner of the file I am trying to delete.

Comment: Also, I have other shared files which behave as they should upon deleting. It's only this particular one that is not leaving "Shared With Me"